# height of partly filled tank

Tags: geometry

I want to derive an expression for the fill level of a water tank with the shape of like a rectangular frustum, similar to the one in the picture:
[image]

I know the values:
$a_1$,$a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$ and the angles from horizontal to each side ($\theta_1$, $\theta_2$) ($\theta_1$ is the angle between the plate $a_1$,$b_1$ to horizontal).

My problem is the volume is a third-order polynomium.
$V = a_3 \cdot h^3 +a_2 \cdot h^2 + a_1 \cdot h +a_0$

and solving for the height gives me the expression for the height:

$h =\\
\frac{\left(12 \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot \left( \sqrt{27 \cdot (a_0 - V)^2 \cdot a3^2 - 18 \cdot a_1 \cdot ((a_0 - V) \cdot a_2 - \frac{(2 \cdot a_1^2)}{9}) \cdot a_3 + 4 \cdot (a_0 - V) \cdot a_2^3 - a_1^2 \cdot a_2^2} \right) \cdot a_3 + 108 \cdot(- a_0 +  V) \cdot a_3^2 + 36 \cdot a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 - 8 \cdot a_2^3\right)^{1/3}}{6 \cdot a_3}\\
-
\frac{2 \cdot(3 \cdot a_1 \cdot a_3 - a_2^2)}{\left(12 \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot \left(\sqrt{27 \cdot (a_0 - V)^2 \cdot a_3^2 - 18 \cdot a_1 \cdot ((a_0 - V) \cdot a_2 - \frac{(2 \cdot a_1^2)}{9}) \cdot a_3 + 4 \cdot (a_0 - V) \cdot a_2^3 - a_1^2 \cdot a_2^2}\right) \cdot a_3 + 108 \cdot (-a_0 + V) \cdot a_3^2 + 36 \cdot a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_3 - 8 \cdot a_2^3\right)^{1/3} \cdot a_3}-\frac{a_2}{(3 \cdot a_3)}$

I don't think this is the right way to do it or at least not the best way to do it there must be a way with a less complicated expression.

Do anyone know a better solution than this ?

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right, you want given the volume of the liquid to derive the height that the tank is filled?

Comment: Yes thats right

Comment: If $a_1,\ a_2,\ b_1,\ b_2$ are known ahead of time, just make a look up table of fill height versus volume and use the table backwards. Or fit a curve to the (backwards) look up table.

Comment: If you place the datum from which $h$ is measured at the lowest point of the tank, then $a_0$ is zero, which straight away significantly reduces the complexity of your expression.

Comment: Face a1a2 is in horisontal plane I want to know the height from that plane to water surface inside tank. But as both the length a and length b is increasing with the height ( conical form) the expression Will be cubic?

Comment: @Nil My bad.  Erroneous comment about reducing to a quadratic deleted.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let "h" be the height of the box:

$ai = a1 + \dfrac{a2-a1}{h}*hi$

$bi = b1 + \dfrac{b2-b1}{h}*hi$

$V = \dfrac{(ai*bi + a1*b1)*hi}{2}$

For know V, solve for "hi".

Answer (score 0):

If you continue the frustum down to its bottom point (making a complete rectangular pyramid), then the volume of the frustum is found by subtracting the volume of the small pyramid (below the frustum) from the volume of the full pyramid.

[image: Inverted rectangular pyramid with length b2, width b1 and height H. Pyramid is cut by a plane parallel to its rectangular base, creating a smaller pyramid at bottom with length a2, width a1 and height h1; and a frustum with height h.]

Let's call the height of your frustum $h = H - h_1$, where $H$ is the height of the full pyramid and $h_1$ is the height of the small pyramid. See that the height of the small pyramid is: $h_1 = \frac{1}{2}a_2 \tan(\theta_1)$

You want to determine $h$ if you know the volume of the frustum ($V$), the lengths $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, and the angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. So, we'll write an equation for the volume of the frustum that includes the variable $h$:

$$\begin{align} V &= \frac{1}{3}b_1 b_2 H - \frac{1}{3}a_1 a_2 h_1\\
&= \frac{1}{3}b_1 b_2\left(h+\frac{1}{2}a_2 \tan(\theta_1)\right)-\frac{1}{6}a_1 a_2^2 \tan(\theta_1)\end{align}$$

Isolating $h$ gives us:

$$h = \frac{6V+a_1 a_2^2 \tan(\theta_1) - b_1 b_2 a_2 \tan(\theta_1)}{2 b_1 b_2}$$